# Number of solutions to $x^2+y^2 = mx+ny$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m,n$ be coprime positive integers. Prove that the number of pairs $(x,y)$ of integers for which $x^2+y^2 = mx+ny$ is equal to the number of divisors (positive and negative) of the number $m^2+n^2$.

We can rewrite the equation to get $$\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}m\right)^2+\left(y-\dfrac{1}{2}n\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}(m^2+n^2).$$ Thus it is a circle centered at $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}m,\dfrac{1}{2}n\right)$ with radius $\dfrac{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}{2}$, but since the coordinates of the center and $\dfrac{1}{4}(m^2+n^2)$ might not be integers, I didn't see how to count the number of integer solutions to the equation.

Comment: Some $m$ should be $n$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe What do you mean?

Comment: In your original post you wrongly calculated $(y-m/2)^2$.  Should be $(y-n/2)^2$.  I've edited that mistake.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

Comment: @martycohen How does that help solve this question?

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $(2x-m)^2+(2y-n)^2=m^2+n^2$, so you want to look at the number of representations of $m^2+n^2$ as the sum of two squares.

Comment: How about if x=m and y=n, then there are infinitely many solutions.